# Select column values and add it in separate column

Tags: sql, plsql

I am not sure how to explain the situation so here is input and required output

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a self join as follows:

```
select T1.id,T1.Name,T2.id as Relid
from TableName T1 join
     TableName T2 on T1.id<>T2.id
order by T1.Name,T2.id
```

Check result on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f35b/6)

Comment: It gives me expected result but taking too much time

Comment: @umesh.chape,  It will take time if your table is big. What we are doing here is joining with the same table with all other records using ID.

Comment: @umesh.chape, the result will have n*(n-1) records in the output. i.e., if you have only 4 records, result will have 4*3=12 records in the output. if you have 300 input records, result will have 89,700 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(ID,VAL) AS
(
    SELECT 1,'A'
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'B'
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'C'
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'D'
)
SELECT C.ID,C.VAL,X.IDD
 FROM CTE AS C
 JOIN
  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID AS IDD FROM CTE AS C2
  )X ON C.ID<>X.IDD
ORDER BY C.ID
```

Could you please try the above if it is suitable

Comment: Thanks but its like for static data. I have SQL view and want to pull data from view  "SELECT employeeid,NAME,,CLID,code,Date,
,HOURS,employeeid from Test1"

Comment: could you please try to replace references to CTE with references to your view

Comment: Sure. I will check